# OpenGL - Tesselation of some intersecting and some non-intersecting polygons

Tags: python, python-3.x, opengl, pyopengl, tessellation

I have a list of several polygons.

Some are completely separated and non-intersecting with other polygons.

And some are fully intersecting and enclosed within other polygons:

[image]

I want to tesselate it to a set of triangles so I can draw them.
I think that I have a code that works - I'm doing something similar to that:

```
tess = gluNewTess()
gluTessBeginPolygon (tess)
for polygon in polygons:
    gluTessBeginContour(tess)
        for point in polygon:
            gluTessVertex(tess, point, point)
gluTessEndPolygon(tess)
gluDeleteTess(tess)
```

I'm wondering if that is the expected way to go?

The main reason I'm asking the question is that as you can see - the entire code is wrapped in a single gluTessBeginPolygon-gluTessEndPolygon. But it is actually a set of different polygons, which seems a bit odd (although it seems to work...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the way to go (see also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640395/pyopengl-tessellating-polygons)).
The "polygon" defined is actually a multi-polygon here, so all that matter are the contours, which you are defining properly.
OpenGL then checks internally whether some contours are self-contained or otherwise complicated and generates the proper polygon/set of polygons --- you can have a look at the code in [PolygonTesselator](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mcfletch/openglcontext/trunk/view/head:/OpenGLContext/scenegraph/polygontessellator.py#L53) or at [this page](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_tessellation.html) for a walkthrough.